# Ajax sending _POST sem maximo de caracters

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Neste ajax o post manda mais que 1000 caracters:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'inserir.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { inseason: document.getElementById('comment').value },
            success: function(result) {
                alert('the request was successfully sent to the server');
            }
        });
```

Mas neste outro tem um maximo de 1000 caracters e não consigo perceber porque.

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var parametros = "inseason=" + document.getElementById('comment').value;

        http.open("POST", "inserir.php", true);

        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) 
            {

                //console.log(http.responseText);
                $('#logs').text(http.responseText);

            }
        }
        http.send(parametros);
```

Comment: Como verificou que o primeiro manda mais de 1000 caracteres e o segundo não?

Comment: tenho uma textarea para por o resultado do script , e no segundo o post so envia 1000 caracters

Comment: E qual é o código do `inserir.php`?

Comment: Coloeque `console.log(http.responseText.length);` após `$('#logs').text(http.responseText);` e veja o que mostra no console

Comment: agora tava a testar quantos cars passava com console.log(http.responseText.length); e descobri que quando passo um & no codigo aquilo confunde como fosse mais parametros e depois so me da os caracters ate ao &

Comment: Coloca `escape()`, assim: `escape(document.getElementById('comment').value)`

Comment: Isso irá escapar os caracteres especiais, como o &.

Comment: É isso mesmo , obrigado

Comment: Já que que dei uma dica e vc achou o erro principal, seria legal se vc postasse uma resposta dizendo como o problema foi resolvido e depois marcar como certa, para dar a pergunta como finalizada. Abs!

Comment: Vou fazer isso mas só posso aceitar a minha resposta depois de dois dias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro que eu tinha era que passava **&** no post e o ajax confundia como fosse outro parâmetro e o parâmetro que eu queria que recebesse o texto só me mostrava os caracteres até ao **&**.

Então eu percebi o erro e o **DvD** disse-me como resolve-lo:

```
escape(document.getElementById('comment').value)
```

Basta mudar isso nos parâmetros.